# Nothing returned from 2D arrays for a simple tic-tac-toe board

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

```
public String tictactoe(String game)
{
    game = game.toUpperCase();
    char[][] board = new char[3][3];
    int loc = 0;
    for( char r = 0; r < board.length; r++ )
    {
        for( char  c = 0; c < board[r].length;  c++)
        {   board[r][c] = game.charAt(loc);
            loc++;
        }
    }
    if ((board[0][0] =='X' && board[0][1] =='X' && board[0][2] =='X') ||
        (board[1][0] =='X' && board[1][1] =='X' && board[1][2] =='X') ||
        (board[2][0] =='X' && board[2][1] =='X' && board[2][2] =='X'))
        return("Player 1 wins horizontally!");
    else if ((board[0][0] =='O' && board[0][1] =='O' && board[0][2] =='O') ||
             (board[1][0] =='O' && board[1][1] =='O' && board[1][2] =='O') ||
             (board[2][0] =='O' && board[2][1] =='O' && board[2][2] =='O'))
        return("Player 2 wins horizontally!");
    else if ((board[0][0] =='X' && board[1][0] =='X' && board[2][0] =='X') ||
             (board[0][1] =='X' && board[1][1] =='X' && board[2][1] =='X') ||
             (board[0][2] =='X' && board[1][2] =='X' && board[2][2] =='X'))
        return("PLayer 2 wins vertically!");
    else if ((board[0][0] =='O' && board[1][0] =='O' && board[2][0] =='O') ||
             (board[0][1] =='O' && board[1][1] =='O' && board[2][1] =='O') ||
             (board[0][2] =='O' && board[1][2] =='O' && board[2][2] =='O'))
        return("Player 2 wins vertically!");
    return "Tie!";
}
```

Above is my code for this method. It reads in a 9 letter string for a tic-tac-toe game and then puts it one by one into a 2D array. I unfortunately have to use this method because this is unfortunately what we're learning, and I've continuously had to bother my teacher about this...

The if statements check each row and column for a winner (I realize it does not check the horizontals). My issue here is nothing is being returned, even though it is supposed to return a string. As I have said I ***have*** to use 2D-arrays here. The goal is to check a tic-tac-toe game and return whom as won.

Comment: Have you done some debug through this?

Comment: The method certainly does *return* something. Maybe you are confusing `return ...` with `System.out.println(...)`, and are mistakenly expecting this method to print something to the console?

Comment: this can be mistake in logic statement. Should breaking into smaller statement for clarity.

Comment: @tana - there is no code path in the sample that returns "nothing" of any kind...

Comment: I tried this code with game = "XOXOXOXOXX" -> it return Tie!. How can i reproduce your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing each instance of this

```
if(board[0][0] =='X' && board[0][1] =='X' && board[0][2] =='X')  ||
   ...
```

With this function:

```
public boolean isRowFilledWith(int row_index, char x_or_o)  {
   return  (board[row_idx][0] == x_or_o  &&
            board[row_idx][1] == x_or_o  &&
            board[row_idx][2] == x_or_o);
}
```

Now, to see if the top-most row contains all x-s, call it with

```
if(isRowFilledWith(0, 'X')  ||
   ...
```

This will make your code a lot more concise, easier to read and *easier to debug*.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
System.out.println(fooObject.tictactoe("XXXXXXOOO");
```

inside your main argument (public static void main(String[] args)

I suspect you've confused `return` and `System.out.println`. The console will not print anything if returned. Instead, returning is what is thrown at the computer after the function is called. Try printing the result of calling the function...THAT is what is returned to the computer and  is only going to be visible if you print it. There may not be any error in your code.

Answer (score 0):

First off, to directly answer your question:

Your function works fine, I locally tested it. I tried both horizontal, and vertical, with both x and o. It must be something you are doing with the caller.

The biggest problem with this code is clarity. You can do quite a bit about clarity by separating the logic into groups.

Clarity can be achieved by making application specific objects.

If you have an object to represent a move, a game, and the marker... you can drastically simplify you code and most of all make it easy to read and debug.

I went ahead and implemented tic tac toe just to kinda explain what I mean by clarity.

Any time you start having massive if else chains and block return statements you may need to take the extra time to break up the problem.

This is fully compililable and I think if you debug through it a few times you will find it is much easier to spot mistakes.

It is also easy to ajust the game... Right now, we have 2 players and a 3 by 3 game.

However, we have extra constructors to adjust the size of the game and to give the gamers some options on what they want thier tic tac toe game to look like.

The major reason to do this is for clarity and debugging.

It is always easier to find issues if you have problem specific methods and problem specific objects.

Below is a fully compilable console application for tic tac toe. In its current form, it plays 100 random 3 by 3 games and prints the results of all 100 games.

The application is also capable of taking your string input as console input and processing the moves.

Notice that we are still using two dimensional arrays, but we hidden away the complexity of using them by encapsulating the array in the Board object.

We also gave a move object so we can store moves to play later. This was useful in creating the loop to play many games, as all the facts about the move are contained in a single object.

Since we created three separate methods for validating the move input. We have a much clearer explanation of what we are validating and why we are doing it.

Most debuggers will also show the objects toString method, so by embedding the game display within the toString() we are allowed to see what the board looks like when we are debugging.

The trick to making clean code that doesn't require alot of comments is to attempt to split out any complexity to its own unit.

You probably will cover more about units of work later, but just keep it in mind, the more simple a method, the more reusable it is. The more single purpose a class is, the better and clearer it is.

My Example:

**Mark.java**
*-This enum is the representation of the mark used by a player to signify their move.*

```
public enum Mark{
    X, Y;
}
```

**TicTacToe.java**

*-This class is your main class
it handles gathering user input, cleaning it, processing it, and displaying the output to the user*

Notice that I am not doing game display anywhere else but the main method. this keeps all display issues localized to one spot. The advantage to breaking up your code into specific objects is knowing where to fix something when it breaks.

```
package com.clinkworks.example;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.clinkworks.example.Move;
import com.clinkworks.example.Board;
import com.clinkworks.example.Mark;

public class TicTacToe {

    //this variable is simply used for output. Since we cant save CAT in the mark enum, we
    // use it to hold cats games.
    private static final String catsGameIdentity = "CAT";

    //this map contains the counts of wins for each symbol
    //it also keeps track of ties and stores it in the map as "CAT"
    //soo.. gamesToWinsMap.get("CAT") will produce the amount of ties.
    private static final Map<String, Integer> gamesToWinsMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String game = args[0].toUpperCase(); //better ways to do this and no validation here.. but it will work
        Board board = new Board();

        //holds our current place in the string passed in from teh console
        int currentStringLocation = 0;

        for(int row = 0; row < 3; row++){ //loop through the rows
            for(int column = 0; column < 3; column++){ //for each row loop through the columns
                if(gameOver(board)){ // we don't care about the rest of the input if the game was won
                    break;
                }

                //convert the symbol to a string for use in teh ValueOf function in the enum class

                String symbol = "" + game.charAt(currentStringLocation); //better than String.valueOf imho

                //allow spaces to represent un marked places
                if(" ".equals(symbol)){
                    currentStringLocation++; //this accounts for spaces in our input
                    break; 
                }
                //convert the string to a Mark enum... over use of strings is a very very bad practice
                Mark nextMarkToPlace = Mark.valueOf(symbol);
                Move move = new Move(row, column, nextMarkToPlace); //we create a move object that encapsulates the complexity of placing the mark on the game board
                board.play(move); //the game already knows how to play itself, just let it
                currentStringLocation++; //increment the posision.
            }
        }

        //since you may not have won the game, or gave a complete string for a cats game, 
        // lets at least display the board for debugging reasons.
        if(board.movesLeft() > 0){
            System.out.println("Board isn't finished, but here is what it looks like basd on your input: ");
            System.out.println(board);
        }

    }

    //call me main if you want to see what I do
    public static void main2(String[] args) {

        //lets play 100 games and see the wins and ties
        playGames(100);

        System.out.println("Number wins by X: " + gamesToWinsMap.get(Mark.X.name()));
        System.out.println("Number wins by O: " + gamesToWinsMap.get(Mark.O.name()));
        System.out.println("Number of ties: " + gamesToWinsMap.get(catsGameIdentity));
    }

    public static void playGames(int count) {
        //play a new game each iteration, in our example, count = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            playGame();
        }
    }

    public static void playGame() {
        //create a new game board. this initalizes our 2d array and lets the complexity of handling that
        // array be deligated to the board object.
        Board board = new Board();

        //we are going to generate a random list of moves. Heres where we are goign to store it
        List<Move> moves = new ArrayList<Move>();

        //we are creating moves for each space on the board.
        for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                moves.add(new Move(row, col));
            }
        }

        //randomize the move list
        Collections.shuffle(moves);

        //do each move
        for (Move move : moves) {
            board.play(move);

            if(gameOver(board)){
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean gameOver(Board board){
        if (board.whoWon() != null) {
            System.out.println("Player with the mark: " + board.whoWon() + " won the game!");
            System.out.println(board);

            Integer winCount = gamesToWinsMap.get(board.whoWon().name());
            winCount = winCount == null ? 1 : winCount + 1;

            gamesToWinsMap.put(board.whoWon().name(), winCount);

            return true;

        } else if (board.movesLeft() == 0) {
            System.out.println("It was a cats game!!");
            System.out.println(board);

            Integer catCount = gamesToWinsMap.get(catsGameIdentity);
            catCount = catCount == null ? 1 : catCount + 1;
            gamesToWinsMap.put(catsGameIdentity, catCount);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**Move.java**

*-This class is responsible for ensuring that only integers are passed to the game board
   and for telling the game board who is doing the move (optional)*

```
    package com.clinkworks.example;

    import com.clinkworks.example.Mark;        

    public class Move {
        private int row;
        private int column;
        private Mark forcedMark;

        public Move(int row, int column) {
            this.row = row;
            this.column = column;
        }

        //the board already knows who should be next. only use this constructor to override
        // what symbol to put on the game board
        public Move(int row, int column, Mark markToPlace){
            this.row = row;
            this.column = column;
            forcedMark = markToPlace;
        }

        public int getRow() {
            return row;
        }

        public int getColumn() {
            return column;
        }

        public Mark getMark(){
            return forcedMark;
        }
    }
```

**Board.java**

*-This is where all the state of the board is managed, who is the next player, who won, and
is there any moves left to play. It also ensures that only valid moves are played.*

```
    package com.clinkworks.example;

    import com.clinkworks.example.Mark;
    import com.clinkworks.example.Move;

    public class Board {

        private final int rowSize;
        private final int columnSize;
        private final Mark[][] gameBoard;
        private Mark currentMark;
        private Mark winningMark;

        /**
        * This constructor defaults the starting player to X with a 3 by 3
        * game.
        */
        public Board() {
            gameBoard = new Mark[3][3];
            currentMark = Mark.X; // X always goes first ;P
            winningMark = null;
            this.rowSize = 3;
            this.columnSize = 3;
        }

        /**
        * This constructor defaults the starting player to X, and lets the
        * board size be adjusted
        */
        public Board(int rowSize, int columnSize) {
            gameBoard = new Mark[rowSize][columnSize];
            currentMark = Mark.X; // X always goes first ;P
            winningMark = null;
            this.rowSize = getRowSize();
            this.columnSize = columnSize;
        }

        /**
        * this constructor allows the players to choose who goes first on a 3
        * by 3 board.
        * 
        * @param firstPlayer
        */
        public Board(Mark firstPlayer) {
            gameBoard = new Mark[3][3];
            currentMark = firstPlayer; // Let the player choose
            winningMark = null;
            rowSize = 3;
            columnSize = 3;
        }

        /**
        * this constructor allows the players to choose who goes first and to
        * choose the size of the board.
        * 
        * @param firstPlayer
        */
        public Board(Mark firstPlayer, int rowSize, int columnSize) {
            gameBoard = new Mark[getRowSize()][columnSize];
            currentMark = firstPlayer; // Let the player choose
            winningMark = null;
            this.rowSize = rowSize;
            this.columnSize = columnSize;
        }

        /**
        * 
        * @return the amount of empty spaces remaining on the game board, or if theres a winning player, zero.
        */
        public int movesLeft() {

            if(whoWon() != null){
                return 0;
            }

            int moveCount = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < getRowSize(); x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < getColumnSize(); y++) {
                    moveCount += getMarkAt(x, y) == null ? 1 : 0;
                }
            }
            return moveCount;
        }

        /**
        * If someone won, this will return the winning player.
        * 
        * @return the winning player
        */
        public Mark whoWon() {
            return winningMark;
        }

        /**
        * This move allows the next player to choose where to place their mark.
        * if a move is played without a player given, it will use the current player variable
        * 
        * as a side affect, the next player in rotation is chosen.
        * 
        * @param Move
        * @return if the game is over, play will return true, otherwise false.
        */
        public boolean play(Move move) {

            if (!validMove(move)) {
                // always fail early
                throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot play " + currentMark + " at " + move.getRow() + ", " + move.getColumn() + "\n" + toString());
            }

            doMove(move);

            boolean playerWon = isWinningMove(move);

            if (playerWon) {
                winningMark = currentMark;
                return true;
            }

            togglePlayer();

            boolean outOfMoves = movesLeft() <= 0;

            return outOfMoves;
        }

        public Mark lastMarkPlayed() {
            return currentMark;
        }

        public int getRowSize() {
            return rowSize;
        }

        public int getColumnSize() {
            return columnSize;
        }

        public Mark getCurrentPlayer() {
            return currentMark;
        }

        public Mark getMarkAt(int row, int column) {
            return gameBoard[row][column];
        }

        private void doMove(Move move) {
            if(move.getMark() != null){
                currentMark = move.getMark();
            }
            gameBoard[move.getRow()][move.getColumn()] = getCurrentPlayer();
        }

        private void togglePlayer() {
            if (currentMark == Mark.X) {
                currentMark = Mark.O;
            } else {
                currentMark = Mark.X;
            }
        }

        /**
         * A valid move is a move where the row and the column are within boundries
         * and no move has been made that the location specified by the move.
         */
        private boolean validMove(Move move) {
            boolean noMarkAtIndex = false;
            boolean indexesAreOk = move.getRow() >= 0 || move.getRow() < getRowSize();
            indexesAreOk = indexesAreOk && move.getColumn() >= 0 || move.getColumn() < getColumnSize();
            if (indexesAreOk) {
                noMarkAtIndex = getMarkAt(move.getRow(), move.getColumn()) == null;
            }
            return indexesAreOk && noMarkAtIndex;
        }

        private boolean isWinningMove(Move move) {
            // since we check to see if the player won on each move
            // we are safe to simply check the last move
            return winsDown(move) || winsAcross(move) || winsDiagnally(move);
        }

        private boolean winsDown(Move move) {
            boolean matchesColumn = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < getColumnSize(); i++) {
                Mark markOnCol = getMarkAt(move.getRow(), i);
                if (markOnCol != getCurrentPlayer()) {
                    matchesColumn = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return matchesColumn;
        }

        private boolean winsAcross(Move move) {
            boolean matchesRow = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < getRowSize(); i++) {
                Mark markOnRow = getMarkAt(i, move.getColumn());
                if (markOnRow != getCurrentPlayer()) {
                    matchesRow = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return matchesRow;
        }

        private boolean winsDiagnally(Move move) {
            // diagnals we only care about x and y being teh same...
            // only perfect squares can have diagnals
            // so we check (0,0)(1,1)(2,2) .. etc
            boolean matchesDiagnal = false;
            if (isOnDiagnal(move.getRow(), move.getColumn())) {
                matchesDiagnal = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < getRowSize(); i++) {
                    Mark markOnDiagnal = getMarkAt(i, i);
                    if (markOnDiagnal != getCurrentPlayer()) {
                        matchesDiagnal = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return matchesDiagnal;
        }

        private boolean isOnDiagnal(int x, int y) {
            if (boardIsAMagicSquare()) {
                return x == y;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private boolean boardIsAMagicSquare() {
            return getRowSize() == getColumnSize();
        }

        //prints out the board in a nice to view display
        public String toString() {
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            for(int y = 0; y < getColumnSize(); y++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < getRowSize(); x++) {
                    Mark mark = getMarkAt(x, y);
                        String markToPrint = "";
                    if (mark == null) {
                        markToPrint = " ";
                    } else {
                        markToPrint = mark.name();
                    }
                    stringBuffer.append("|").append(markToPrint);
                }
                stringBuffer.append("|\n");
            }
            return stringBuffer.toString();
        }
    }
}
```